# Can someone please help where can i get android AFFDEX SDK?? I have tried to download but in vain

Tags: affdex-sdk

I am developing an application which mines emotion, and I need that sdk toolkit. I have heard about it. Can someone please help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

You can contact Affectiva at https://www.affectiva.com/contact-us.